# How do I define and use IOn[X]SetListenerImplementor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am reading through the source code for Xamarin and came across these two dialogs: the [`TimePickerDialog`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/TimePickerDialog.cs) and [`DatePickerDialog`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/DatePickerDialog.cs).

When reading through these, I see that there is an object being instantiated that I am unable to find anywhere else.

I'm wondering what the purpose of these listener implementors are as well as how to actually go about creating my own (or if I even need to make my own). My goal was to create some custom `PickerDialog`s so I was checking to see how they are already implemented.

Here's the `TimePickerDialog`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Android.App {

    public partial class TimePickerDialog {

        public TimePickerDialog (Android.Content.Context context, EventHandler<TimeSetEventArgs> callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, bool is24HourView) 
            // ** The IOnTimeSetListenerImplementor here **
            : this (context, new IOnTimeSetListenerImplementor () { Handler = callBack }, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView) {}

        public TimePickerDialog (Android.Content.Context context, int theme, EventHandler<TimeSetEventArgs> callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, bool is24HourView) 
            : this (context, theme, new IOnTimeSetListenerImplementor () { Handler = callBack }, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView) {}

    }
}
```

Here's the `DatePickerDialog`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Android.App {

    public partial class DatePickerDialog {

        public partial class DateSetEventArgs {

            public DateTime Date {
                get { return new DateTime (Year, Month + 1, DayOfMonth); }
            }

#if ANDROID_24
            [Obsolete ("This parameter in DateTimePickerDialog constructor is removed in Android API, so it will vanish from this automatically generated type too.")]
            public int MonthOfYear {
                get { return Month; }
            }
#else
            public int Month {
                get { return monthOfYear; }
            }
#endif
        }

        public DatePickerDialog (Android.Content.Context context, EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            // ** The IOnDateSetListenerImplementor here **
            : this (context, new IOnDateSetListenerImplementor () { Handler = callBack }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) {}

        public DatePickerDialog (Android.Content.Context context, int theme, EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            : this (context, theme, new IOnDateSetListenerImplementor () { Handler = callBack }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) {}

        public void UpdateDate (DateTime date)
        {
            UpdateDate (date.Year, date.Month - 1, date.Day);
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus question: Why are these two classes defined as partial classes? I can't find the other parts anywhere else in this repo. Perhaps I am not searching correctly, or maybe it's for future expansion?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't put code in images. Copy/paste the text itself into the question. (3 backticks on a line before it, and after it, will format it nicely.) People might want to search on some text.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I'll replace that with an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following when I searched through the metadata of `Android.App.DatePickerDialog` (easy enough to do by Right-Clicking a class name in Visual Studio and selecting Go To Definition):

```
#region Assembly Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v11.0\Mono.Android.dll
#endregion

#nullable enable

using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Interop;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Android.App
{
    [Register("android/app/DatePickerDialog", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public class DatePickerDialog : AlertDialog, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable, IJavaPeerable, DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener
    {
        [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "", ApiSince = 24)]
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context);
        [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;I)V", "", ApiSince = 24)]
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId);
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context, EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
        [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener;III)V", "")]
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context, IOnDateSetListener? listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
        [Register(".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener;III)V", "")]
        public DatePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId, IOnDateSetListener? listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
        protected DatePickerDialog(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);

        public virtual DatePicker DatePicker { get; }
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers { get; }
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        protected override Type ThresholdType { get; }
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass { get; }

        public event EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> DateSet;

        [Register("onClick", "(Landroid/content/DialogInterface;I)V", "GetOnClick_Landroid_content_DialogInterface_IHandler")]
        public virtual void OnClick(IDialogInterface dialog, int which);
        [Register("onDateChanged", "(Landroid/widget/DatePicker;III)V", "GetOnDateChanged_Landroid_widget_DatePicker_IIIHandler")]
        public virtual void OnDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
        [Register("setOnDateSetListener", "(Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener;)V", "GetSetOnDateSetListener_Landroid_app_DatePickerDialog_OnDateSetListener_Handler", ApiSince = 24)]
        public virtual void SetOnDateSetListener(IOnDateSetListener? listener);
        public void UpdateDate(DateTime date);
        [Register("updateDate", "(III)V", "GetUpdateDate_IIIHandler")]
        public virtual void UpdateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);

        [Register("android/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener", "", "Android.App.DatePickerDialog/IOnDateSetListenerInvoker")]
        public interface IOnDateSetListener : IJavaObject, IDisposable, IJavaPeerable
        {
            [Register("onDateSet", "(Landroid/widget/DatePicker;III)V", "GetOnDateSet_Landroid_widget_DatePicker_IIIHandler:Android.App.DatePickerDialog/IOnDateSetListenerInvoker, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]
            void OnDateSet(DatePicker? view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
        }

        public class DateSetEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public DateSetEventArgs(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);

            public DateTime Date { get; }
            [Obsolete("This parameter in DateTimePickerDialog constructor is removed in Android API, so it will vanish from this automatically generated type too.")]
            public int MonthOfYear { get; }
            public int Year { get; }
            public int Month { get; }
            public int DayOfMonth { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that the `IOnDateSetListener` interface was being defined right in the class. I also noticed the class was no longer marked `partial`.

I then was also able to find [`DatePickerDialog+IOnDateSetListener.xml`](https://github.com/xamarin/android-api-docs/blob/b1743ec39b68aef9983cff521e2f693e10e5ddcd/docs/Mono.Android/en/Android.App/DatePickerDialog+IOnDateSetListener.xml):

```
<Type Name="DatePickerDialog+IOnDateSetListener" FullName="Android.App.DatePickerDialog+IOnDateSetListener">
  <TypeSignature Language="C#" Value="public interface DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener : Android.Runtime.IJavaObject, IDisposable, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable" />
  <TypeSignature Language="ILAsm" Value=".class nested public interface auto ansi abstract DatePickerDialog/IOnDateSetListener implements class Android.Runtime.IJavaObject, class Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable, class System.IDisposable" />
  <TypeSignature Language="DocId" Value="T:Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener" />
  <TypeSignature Language="F#" Value="type DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener = interface&#xA;    interface IJavaObject&#xA;    interface IDisposable&#xA;    interface IJavaPeerable" />

...

 <AttributeName Language="C#">[Android.Runtime.Register("android/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener", "", "Android.App.DatePickerDialog/IOnDateSetListenerInvoker")]</AttributeName>
      <AttributeName Language="F#">[&lt;Android.Runtime.Register("android/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener", "", "Android.App.DatePickerDialog/IOnDateSetListenerInvoker")&gt;]</AttributeName>
   
...

<a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener" title="Reference documentation">Android platform documentation</a>

...
```

and [`DatePickerDialog.xml`](https://github.com/xamarin/android-api-docs/blob/b1743ec39b68aef9983cff521e2f693e10e5ddcd/docs/Mono.Android/en/Android.App/DatePickerDialog.xml):

```
<Type Name="DatePickerDialog" FullName="Android.App.DatePickerDialog">
  <TypeSignature Language="C#" Value="public class DatePickerDialog : Android.App.AlertDialog, Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener, Android.Widget.DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener, IDisposable, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable" />
  <TypeSignature Language="ILAsm" Value=".class public auto ansi beforefieldinit DatePickerDialog extends Android.App.AlertDialog implements class Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener, class Android.Runtime.IJavaObject, class Android.Widget.DatePicker/IOnDateChangedListener, class Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable, class System.IDisposable" />
  <TypeSignature Language="DocId" Value="T:Android.App.DatePickerDialog" />
  <TypeSignature Language="F#" Value="type DatePickerDialog = class&#xA;    inherit AlertDialog&#xA;    interface IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener&#xA;    interface IJavaObject&#xA;    interface IDisposable&#xA;    interface IJavaPeerable&#xA;    interface DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener" />
  <AssemblyInfo>
    <AssemblyName>Mono.Android</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
  </AssemblyInfo>
  <Base>
    <BaseTypeName>Android.App.AlertDialog</BaseTypeName>
  </Base>
  <Interfaces>
    <Interface>
      <InterfaceName>Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener</InterfaceName>
    </Interface>
    <Interface>
      <InterfaceName>Android.Runtime.IJavaObject</InterfaceName>
    </Interface>
    <Interface>
      <InterfaceName>Android.Widget.DatePicker+IOnDateChangedListener</InterfaceName>
    </Interface>
...
```

Both of the aforementioned files mention it. My best guess would be that there are build events that use this information to build cross-language methods and inject them into partial classes. The c# `DatePickerDialog`(from metadata) may be the result of compile time events merging the [`DatePickerDialog`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/DatePickerDialog.cs) - mentioned in the question - with the information contained in the XML files when the Xamarin libraries are built and packaged.

The listener interfaces seem to be specific to the behavior of `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`, and don't seem to be necessary in every situation.

Instead of trying to replicate that behavior, creating a custom dialog that extends [`AlertDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.alertdialog?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) and calling the [`SetView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.alertdialog.setview?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12#android-app-alertdialog-setview(android-views-view)) method may be all that is needed.

**EDIT:**
There is also a `Popup` class included in the Xamarin Community Toolkit that makes it very easy to make custom dialogs like the ones referenced in the question. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup).